# Set background to a picture if JSON does not load

Tags: java, android, json

I am parsing a json array in a viewpager and I currently have the viewpager loading a fragment "panel" into a recyclerview. However, if the jsonarray does not load I want the fragment_dashboard as shown below to show an image how do i go about doing this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context=".MainActivitys.Dashboard">
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_dashboard_recycler"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting a background like this

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

And then you could programmatically hide it like this

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_dashboard_recycler);
recyclerView.setBackgroundResource(null); //or some blank background from drawable
```